# How can I reduce the size of Docker images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have Node.js app which I am running as a docker container. Here is
   a Dockerfile for that application.

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm nodejs-legacy vim

RUN mkdir /consumer_portal
ADD . /consumer_portal
WORKDIR /consumer_portal

RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Can I modify something in this Dockerfile to reduce the docker image size

Comment: Don't install vim? Build outside image?

Comment: Use Alpine base image

Comment: @Aurélien `anapsix/alpine-java` is that what you are saying:What could i have instead of java for node

Comment: Alpine is a minimal Linux distr. https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/ for e.g.

Comment: I found this really useful: https://learnk8s.io/blog/smaller-docker-images
Also the examples in this post are for nodejs images

Answer (score 10):

Using [the official node alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) as a base image, as most here suggested, is a simple solution to reduce the overall size of the image, because even the base alpine image is a lot smaller compared to the base ubuntu image.

A Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM node:alpine

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

RUN mkdir /consumer_portal \
    && npm install -g express path

COPY . /consumer_portal
WORKDIR /consumer_portal

RUN npm cache clean \
    && npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "node",  "server.js" ]
```

It's nearly the same and should work as expected. Most of the commands from your ubuntu image can be applied the same way in the alpine image.

When I add mock-data to be create a similar project as you might have, results in an ubuntu image with a size of 491 MB and the alpine version is only 62.5 MB big:

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED          SIZE
alpinefoo    latest    8ca6f338475e    5 minutes ago    62.5MB
ubuntufoo    latest    38620a1bd5a6    6 minutes ago    491MB
```

Comment: This is only true if the dominant contribution to the size of the image is the base layer (which e.g. data scientists are finding out is often not the case)

Answer (score 6):

Try to pack all `RUN` instructions together, it will reduce the number of intermediate images. (But it won"t reduce the size of the final image).

Adding `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` after `apt-get update` will reduce image size by removing all useless apt-get stuff.

You may also remove `vim` from your image in the last RUN instruction.

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm nodejs-legacy vim \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir /consumer_portal

ADD . /consumer_portal
WORKDIR /consumer_portal

RUN npm install -g express \
    && npm install -g path \
    && npm cache clean \
    && npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didn't work for me, Only few MB get reduce.

Comment: If you want to use Ubuntu as base image, you won't be able to reduce much more MB. Perhaps you should think about change your base image to Alpine or something similar.

Comment: @JoséAntonioLópez Dont know alpine, but feel free to edit my post to improve answer ;)

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh There is no much you can do to drastically reduce image size (except for switching from ubunto to something else).

Comment: Another option is to go with light weight base containers such as Alpine linux

Answer (score 4):

Consider using this:
Consider using a `--no-install-recommends` when `apt-get` installing packages. This will result in a smaller image size. For more information, see this blog post

There is a good blog to tell you a few steps to go to reduce image size.

Tips to Reduce Docker Image Sizes
https://hackernoon.com/tips-to-reduce-docker-image-sizes-876095da3b34

Answer (score 3):

1) Moving to Alpine is probably the best bet. I just ported an Ubuntu docker file to Alpine and went from 1.5GB to 585MB. I followed [these instructions](https://coderwall.com/p/s4ofoq/docker-why-i-prefer-alpine-as-base-instead-of-ubuntu). Note, you'll be using apk instead of apt-get and the Alpine package names are a bit different.

2) It is also possible to reduce layers by merging run commands (each new run command creates a new layer).

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm nodejs-legacy vim
RUN npm install -g express path && npm cache clean && npm install
```

3) You may also be interested in [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages) wherein you only copy necessary components to the final image.

Answer (score 1):

## Image generated at the first step , alias: builder

## Copy the product of the first step image to the current image, only one image layer is used, saving the number of image layers of the previous step.

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /web-console 
ADD . /web-console
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build 

FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /web-console
COPY --from=builder . /web-console
CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-start"]
```

## here an example of Java with Maven : 2 steps

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine as BUILD
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app/
COPY src /app/src/
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=BUILD /app/target/*.jar  application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/application.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you base on Ubuntu then a smart move is to make this

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cwhatever-you-want \
    vim \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The last line will clear a lot :)
You should always apt-get update in same line, because otherwise it will be cached and not fired on next builds if you add another lib to install.

Comment: Yes exactly. I am base on Ubuntu

Comment: Can you please correct me with my Dockerfile ?? Where should I Put the piece of code u have provided

Comment: When I Try `FROM mhart/alpine-node:base-6` at the first line in my Docekrfile insted of ubuntu My docker images itself are not building

Comment: Alpine, is slightly different, see http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Update_the_Package_list

Comment: Anthony showed you example post over mine ... won't be copy-pasting it again because it'll be same :)

Answer (score 0):

The image size of a container is an issue that should be addressed properly.

Some suggest to use the *alpine* distribution to save space.

That in principle is a good suggestion as there is a *nodejs* image for *alpine* that is ready to be used.

But you have to be carefull here, because you have to build all the binaries. Even *node_modules* usually contain just javascript packages, in some case you have binary that have to be build.

If your dockerfile is working right now, this should not be your case, but as you're moving from an *ubuntu* to a different kind of image it's better to keep in mind that all binaries that you need to use in the future have to be compiled in a *alpine* image.

Said that you should consider how you use your image before choose where to cut size.

Is your application a single application that lives alone just in a own container without any other node app around?

In case the answer is no, you should be aware that the size of each image in the local docker registry is not counted as summary to obtain the total used size.

Instead you have to split each image in the basic layers and sum each uniq layer.

What I mean here is that the single image is not so important if you have many node apps that run on a node.

You can save space by sharing the *node_modules* exporting it as a volume that contains all the needed dependencies.

Or better, you can start from an official *nodejs* image to create an intermediate image that contains the root of dependencies of you apps. For example *expressjs* and *path*. And then install in each application image the dedicated dependencies.

So you gain the advantage to share the layers in common reducing the total used size of the local docker registry.

**Minor considerations**

You don't need to install *express* and *path* globally inside a container image.

Do you really need *vim* in a container?
Consider that modify a container is not safe even in development. You can use the volume to point resources on your server file system.
Or copy in/out a file or folder from your container when running.
And if you just need to read something, just use commands like less, more or cat.